# Waiting for a method Angular 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I have a extern requisition on my service class

```
public getEndereco(cep: string){
        return this.http.get("http://viacep.com.br/ws/" + cep + "/json",{
            responseType: 'text'
        });
    }
```

After that, I catch the return json and put into a objecton my class Util

```
public getEndereco(cep: string): Endereco{
        let endereco = new Endereco();
        this.serviceUtil.getEndereco(cep)
          .subscribe((response)=>{
            let json = JSON.parse(response);
            endereco.cep = json.cep;
            endereco.rua = json.logradouro;
            endereco.complemento = json.complemento;
            endereco.bairro = json.bairro;
            endereco.cidade = json.localidade;
            endereco.estado = this.buscarEstadoSigla(json.uf);
          },(erro)=>{
            console.log(erro);
          });

          return endereco;
      }
```

In my layer of vision, I get this object and make this:

```
private getEndereco(){
    this.endereco = this.util.getEndereco(this.endereco.cep);
    this.estado = this.endereco.estado;
  }
```

But always "this.endereco.estado" comes null.
I know angular work with asynchronous.
How can I expect the object "this.endereco" to return from the return to after assign as the bottom line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should instead modify `getEndereco` to return the `Observable`, like this:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

public getEndereco(cep: string): Endereco{     
    return this.serviceUtil.getEndereco(cep)
      .pipe(map((response)=>{
        let endereco = new Endereco();
        let json = JSON.parse(response);
        endereco.cep = json.cep;
        endereco.rua = json.logradouro;
        endereco.complemento = json.complemento;
        endereco.bairro = json.bairro;
        endereco.cidade = json.localidade;
        endereco.estado = this.buscarEstadoSigla(json.uf);
        return endereco;
      }));
  }
```

You can then subscribe, like this:

```
private getEndereco(){
    this.util.getEndereco(this.endereco.cep).subscribe(endereco => {
        this.endereco = endereco;
        this.estado = this.endereco.estado;
    });

}
```

Comment: Do I need import something ? 
Because I can put the function "map" it's inexistent

Comment: @BrunoMonteiro Sorry, wasn't sure what version of rxjs you were using. Try the updated code above

Comment: Thank you so much. I save my life Hahahahah 
I need study more about observables.

Answer (score 1):

One other thing: there's no need to translate everything from json if it's a known object. Create an endereco.model.ts and import it. Then you can use it as an object.

```
 this.serviceUtil.getEndereco(cep)
        .pipe((response: Endereco) => {
         let endereco = response;
         return endereco;
         })
```

Then your model:

```
export class Endereco {
    cep : string;
    rua : string;
    complemento: string;
}
```